How to get ads to refresh using googletag.pubads().refresh() but not send their tracker?
I am very much new to google ads implementation. I have a scenario where I am not able to find any particular solution.
There are certain ads on the page which are lazyloaded. However, when the page loads, the first call goes to https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?pvsid= which contains all ad IDs. And after that, there is another call that is sent only for these lazy loaded ads. This is causing duplicates in tracking. The function that is used to send the lazyloaded ads is as below:
googletag.pubads().refresh(lazyloadedAds);
Is there any solution to resolve this issue? I am looking for only one call to be made. (If I remove above line of code, it stops rendering these ads, hence cannot remove the same).
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

You could try these
googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
// Define ad slots here
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.enableServices();

// Refresh ads
googletag.pubads().refresh([/* array of slots */]);

